# Binding observablecollection<xmlNode> to wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, wpfdatagrid

I have an observable collection containing XML nodes and I want to bind it to a datagrid.

I know I probably should be using XML dataprovider to bind with but I am experiencing flickering when scrolling so I'm trying out a few different options.

I am trying to bind defined columns to different items in the xml.

XML:

```
<name>
    name1
</name>
<id>
    id1
</id>
```

Code Behind:

```
oc = new ObservableCollection<XmlNode>(listNodes);
dtgMain.ItemsSource = oc;
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dtgMain" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowHeight="25" IsReadOnly="True"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" Width="Auto" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding id}" Width="Auto" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Do you still need to use XPath when binding against XmlNode objects?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx

Comment: Not sure Andy was hoping you guys would be able to help with that :)

Comment: Give it a try :) just replace the Binding property with XPath and see.

Comment: I actually think I'm talking poop right now that's why it's not an answer lol